# Not able to run django because of cache

Tags: django, django-models

I am not able to run django even any command like `migrate`, `makemigrations`.
I am facing this below error

```
ValueError: Related model 'blog.User' cannot be resolved
```

I don't have any app with name 'blog'. Don't know where this app coming from.

This is my settings.py file

```
"""
Django settings for pushnoty project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '6rr$mj_@+*^5a#w=2-#koxj2nv2kpeb&0#jw0%-71fr@9@y)qc'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'fcm_django',
    'core'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'pushnoty.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'pushnoty.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    # {
    #     'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    # },
    # {
    #     'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    # },
    # {
    #     'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    # },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Error:

```
$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, fcm_django, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying admin.0004_auto_20190722_1126...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 203, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 216, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
    return self.target_field.rel_db_type(connection=connection)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 878, in target_field
    return self.foreign_related_fields[0]
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 632, in foreign_related_fields
    return tuple(rhs_field for lhs_field, rhs_field in self.related_fields if rhs_field)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 619, in related_fields
    self._related_fields = self.resolve_related_fields()
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 604, in resolve_related_fields
    raise ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.remote_field.model)
ValueError: Related model 'blog.User' cannot be resolved
```

Comment: It looks like you defined a `ForeignKey('blog.user', ...)`?

Comment: No, I don't create any model yet.

Comment: @ManzulurHoqueRumi: perhaps the `*.pyc` (not `*.py`) files are still not update. You can remove these (the compiled python files)

Comment: I deleted all *.pyc from my project.

Comment: what's fcm_django and what's in core? Can you also show the entire error trace?

Comment: @dirkgroten fcm_django is third party app and core is my created app and no model is not in core app. Updated with complete errors.

Comment: Django doesn't have a migration **admin.0004_auto_20190722_1126**, so I don't understand where this migration comes from. Do a file search for a file name starting with **0004_auto_20190722** to see where this is defined.

Comment: make sure you running the command in your actual project directory

Comment: @dirkgroten Django have this file. I have seen in path `site-packages\django\contrib\admin\migrations`

Comment: I have no idea where you got your django from, but [this is the latest](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/admin/migrations) source code. No 0004 file. Re-install your Django.

Comment: @Harun-Ur-Rashid I am running from actual project. I faced this issue in pyhcarm also then cleared caches from Pycharm then it was working fine, now working in vscode and still facing this issue.

Comment: @dirkgroten you are right, I don't know where this file coming from. I opened the file and find this lines

`models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='blog.User', verbose_name='user')` Now got it working.

Comment: Voting to close as this question is of no help to anyone else. Using the official Django distribution would never cause this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working now. Found a file in admin migrations named `0004_auto_20190722_1126`. Removed the file. Don't understand where this file came from but I can see it's generated by Django 2.1.9.

File contents were:

```
# Generated by Django 2.1.9 on 2019-07-22 05:26

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('admin', '0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='logentry',
            name='user',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='blog.User', verbose_name='user'),
        ),
    ]
```

Thanks @dirkgroten for pointing out this file.

Comment: so you were using some modified version of Django. Not good, make sure you use pip to install Django from the official source. there might be other changes. Don't just remove this one file.

Comment: "generated by Django 2.1.9" doesn't mean it's part of Django, it's just what Django adds on every migration file when you run `makemigrations`. Someone changed the `LogEntry` model inside your Django distribution and ran `makemigrations`.

Comment: No, I didn't modify any file. I always use virtualenv but this time I am not using virtualenv and this file was there. Still don't understand where it came from.